# Can single ssrs report can be configured dynamic connectionstring through report designer?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Let me explain my scenario as below,
Our project works for multiple departments under one main administration.Each dept have individual database.The databases will be connected dynamically from admin database.I'm creating report for one specific database.How can I configure the same report for multiple database?

Answer (score 0):

The same report will retrieve data from diferent databases, rigth? You can send the Server Name/ Initial Catalog through parameters, and use them in the connectiongString of your report.

1) Add the parameters, say, SERVER_NAME and DATABASE.

2) Go to **Report Data** > **Data Sources** and open the Properties from your data source (double click). Under **General setting**, click on the *expression* button on the left of the **Connection String** textBox and change the value to

```
="Data Source=" & Parameters!SERVER_NAME.Value & ";Initial Catalog=" & Parameters!DATABASE.Value
```

[Like shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRHaN.png)

Hope it helps.